# submit no form com jquery não funciona

Tags: jquery, formulário, formulário-submeter

Tenho um formulário e dentro deste form tenho um input do tipo file.

```html
<form id="formulario" method="post" action="upload.php">
  <input id="imagem" name="imagem" type="file" class="da-custom-file customfile-input" >
</form>
```

e no jQuery estou tentou tentando dar o *submit* no formulário:

```js
$('#imagem').live('change',function(){

  $('#formulario').submit(function(){
    alert('teste');
  });                   
});
```

So que o *submit* não funciona. No caso ele não da o *alert()* com a mensagem 
`teste`.

Alguém tem ideia do que eu possa estar fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 10):

Quase lá, mas precisas separar o código:

1. Tens que anexar o `alert()` ao `submit` do formulário;
2. No evento que escuta a alteração do `input`, deverás disparar o envio do formulário.

**[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/sTqSf/)**

```js
// ao alterar o elemento #imagem
$('#imagem').on('change',function(){ 
   $('#formulario').submit();
});

// ao submeter o formulário #formulario
$('#formulario').submit(function(){
    alert('teste');
});
```

<sup>Troquei o [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) por [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) porque nas versões recentes de jQuery a recomendação é o uso do `.on()`.</sup>

**Nota:**
Um formulário com upload de ficheiros deverá conter o [atributo enctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype):

```html
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Ficando:

```html
<form id="formulario" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```